# Installing Fenics for Dolfin using Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, installation, fenics

In order to install the module dolfin for Python one has to install Fenics.
I'm working with Anaconda on Windows.

I tried to install Fenics writing on the Anaconda Prompt : `conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics`

And this error appears :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I see is a spelling mistake and using **cond-forge** instead of **conda-forge**. But other than that fenics is only available for Mac and Linux versions of Anaconda. So perhaps you should use Docker.